# How can I inherit a schema but maintain separate collections using mongoose.js and node.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a schema that I need to maintain as an exact copy of another schema, but keep these documents in separate collections.

```
var someSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    "foo": {"type": String, "required": true, "index": true},
    "bar": {"type": String, "required": true, "index": true},
});
```

The goal I'm after is a simple way to inherit the exact same schema to another model/collection without having to remember to update the second schema every time I make changes to the first.

i.e.

```
var someOtherSchema = mongoose.Schema( < some magic here >);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in an object and reuse the object:

```
var schemaObj = {
    "foo": {"type": String, "required": true, "index": true},
    "bar": {"type": String, "required": true, "index": true},
}

var someSchema = new mongoose.Schema(schemaObj, { collection: 'some' });    
var someOtherSchema = new mongoose.Schema(schemaObj, { collection: 'someOther' });

var someModel = mongoose.model('SomeModel', someSchema);
var someOtherModel = mongoose.model('someOtherModel', someOtherSchema);
```

Comment: Just edited the answer, please let me know if it solves

Comment: That is a viable solution, but I wanted avoid tampering with the original schema file to mitigate code obfuscation. What I actually ended up doing was to simply export the 'someSchema' like so:

module.exports = mongoose.model("SomeOther", mongoose.model("Some").schema);